# NameError: name 'QgsMapLayerRegistry' is not defined

Tags: qgis

I am using Qgis 3.4.9. How can i fix To fix the error: NameError: global name 'QgsMapLayerRegistry' is not defined.

from qgis.core import QgsMapLayerRegistry 
Is not working in Qgis 3.4.9

```
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(point_layer)
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

QgsMapLayerRegistry: Its functionality has been moved to QgsProject.

Syntax:

```
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(your_Qgs_whaterver_Layer)
```

Example:

```
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(point_layer)
```